# How to iterate ViewBag names inside foreach loop?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, viewbag

I managed to find in SO questions regarding looping through `ViewBag` objects, but my issue is how to use iteration to name `ViewBag` inside of it.

But starting from the beginning. Inside of my **Razor View** I have a code, that triggers scripts depending on passed `ViewBag`:

```
@if (ViewBag.TermsChecked == "false")
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("termschecked").style.border = "2px solid #E24941";
    </script>
}
else if (ViewBag.TermsChecked == "true")
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("termschecked").style.border = "unset";
    </script>
}

@if (ViewBag.LoginCaptchaChecked == "false")
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("logincaptchachecked").style.border = "2px solid #E24941";
    </script>
}
else if (ViewBag.LoginCaptchaChecked == "true")
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("logincaptchachecked").style.border = "unset";
    </script>
}

@if (ViewBag.RegisterCaptchaChecked == "false")
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("registercaptchachecked").style.border = "2px solid #E24941";
    </script>
}
else if (ViewBag.RegisterCaptchaChecked == "true")
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("registercaptchachecked").style.border = "unset";
    </script>
}

@if (ViewBag.CaptchaChecked == "false")
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("captchachecked").style.border = "2px solid #E24941";
    </script>
}
else if (ViewBag.CaptchaChecked == "true")
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("captchachecked").style.border = "unset";
    </script>
}
```

To keep it **DRY** I want to create a loop through `ViewBag` names, but I am not sure how to pass **item** into `ViewBag` name in the loop. Until now I tried 2 approaches already, that did not work:

```
@{string[] viewbags = new string[] { ViewBag.TermsChecked, ViewBag.LoginCaptchaChecked, ViewBag.RegisterCaptchaChecked, ViewBag.CaptchaChecked };}


@foreach (string item in viewbags)
{
    if (item == "false")
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("@item.ToLower()").style.border = "2px solid #E24941";
        </script>
    }
    else if (item == "true")
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("@item.ToLower()").style.border = "unset";
        </script>
    }
}
```

and

```
@{string[] viewbags = new string[] { "TermsChecked", "LoginCaptchaChecked", "RegisterCaptchaChecked", "CaptchaChecked" }}


@foreach (string item in viewbags)
{
    @if (ViewBag.item == "false")
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("@item.ToLower()").style.border = "2px solid #E24941";
        </script>
    }
    else if (ViewBag.TermsChecked == "true")
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("@item.ToLower()").style.border = "unset";
        </script>
    }
}
```

Both are not triggering any script, like they should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to modify your Viewbag like :

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    items.Add(new Item { key = "LoginCaptchaChecked", value = "false" });
    items.Add(new Item { key = "RegisterCaptchaChecked", value = "true" });
    ViewBag.showHidelist = items;
    return View();
}
public class Item { 
    public string key { get; set; }

    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

And in page you can dynamically set the border with :

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.showHidelist)
{
    if (@item.value=="true")
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("@item.key.ToLower()").style.border = "2px solid #E24941";
        </script>
    }
    else
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("@item.key.ToLower()").style.border = "unset";
        </script>
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually this solution inspired me to solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using **for** can solve your problem.

**Code**:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.showHideList.Count(); i++)
{
    Item itm = ViewBag.showHideList[i];

    ...
}
```